# Custom UITableViewCell in Center of Screen / UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Storyboard with a UITableView

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/gb4bx.png]

In the UITableView I list custom UITableViewCell's

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/PT2Cm.png]

I thought I could use "autoresizing" in a UITableViewCell like in a view:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/Hxmel.png]

But I can't.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/7FLeu.png]

This is how it is (not in center).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZkrN.png]

This is how it should be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBmzT.png]

How can I make this right?

Comment: You should totally use Auto Layout. Autoresizing is technic from the past.